# Plotting correlation scatter matrix plot in Julia

Tags: plot, julia

I would like to plot data in a particular `DataFrame` obtained from `RDataests`,

```
julia> prestige = dataset("car", "Prestige")
```

The `DataFrame` consists of various columns, but I am interested in plotting three of them viz. `Prestige`, `Income` and `Education`. I would like to have a matrix of scatter plots, like the one obtained using `R` as shown below,

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [StatPlots](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/StatPlots.jl)?

```
using StatPlots, RDatasets; pyplot()
prestige = dataset("car", "Prestige");
corrplot(Array(prestige[[:Prestige, :Income, :Education]]), bins=10)
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks.